# Embedding scripts in text-editor

Tags: unix, emacs, text-editor

I am looking for a text editor that support embedding scripts (Perl in my case) in the text you write.

I understand that something like it is possible through Emacs, but am not sure how and what.

The idea is to generate reports that contain the output of the embedded scripts, which are run while generating the report (if not already in previous versions of the report).

Comment: wow.. its like you are reading org-babel introduction with out naming it..:)

Answer (score 1):

The Babel package in Emacs can do this. See the introductory tutorial [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/).

Answer (score 0):

[sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) does that in a limited way (R only).